# Как получить доступ к функции get_post?

Tags: wordpress

Пытаюсь получить доступ к функции get_post().
в интернете прочитал, что для этого надо подключить файл

```
define('SHORTINIT', true);
require_once('../../../wp-load.php' );
```

но при попытке вызвать функцию выдает критическую ошибку, что такой функции нет

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_post()
```

Comment: Зачем ты подключаешь и откуда? Внятно опиши что хочешь решить.

Comment: Убери SHORTINIT. С ним надо понимать, что ты делаешь, и откуда какие функции берутся.

Comment: Сначала поясни где и как ты пытаешься вызвать get_post. Дело в том, что если ты бросил файл в корне и обращаешься к нему, то да, ты ничего не получишь, поскольку get_post это функция ядра, а у тебя оно 100% не загружено. get_post Вешают уже на хуках WP, либо костылями прогружают часть ядра. **Но вопрос - ЗАЧЕМ**? Кроме того ты пишешь require_once('../../../wp-load.php' ); Путь весьма относителен, всё зависти от того, где ты его вызываешь.